# Jenkins : Not able to send slack notifications using Global Slack Notifier plugin 2.18

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack

I had Global Slack Notifier version 2.x earlier and it was working fine.
I migrated to Global Slack Notifier 2.18 plugin and it stopped working. 
Now, there is NO text-box to enter integration token. 
Also I have generated the Slack compatible app URL like (edited tokens)

https://hooks.slack.com/services/T6sHRwFeQCH2/BGrKfU7t9K5F/dqPlggttrrffbbgexWClfdVCyG
But it's also not working

Can anyone please correct me if I am missing anything.

Also in /usr/logs/jenkins/jenkins.log file, shows following logs

```
Mar 01, 2019 5:20:40 PM jenkins.plugins.slack.StandardSlackService publish
WARNING: Response Code: 404
Mar 01, 2019 5:20:50 PM jenkins.plugins.slack.StandardSlackService publish
WARNING: Slack post may have failed. Response: null
Mar 01, 2019 5:20:50 PM jenkins.plugins.slack.StandardSlackService publish
WARNING: Response Code: 404
```

Answer (score 0):

In Slack install **Jenkins CI** app, click **Add Configuration** and follow setup instruction.

[image]

In Jenkins configuration:
[image]

Comment: In app credentials in slack there are many items, which one i need to pass in secret?